# Adding my flex project to github

Tags: flex4, github

What to commit and what to ignore when adding a flex project to github?
Keep in mind that I want to share it with others and accept pull requests.

Comment: Mmm i'm not a flex programmer, but i think that your question is too general. Usually in every project you want to host is your care to upload all sources, scripts, and everything needed to make the project compile and working correctly. You can exclude the compiled objects.

Comment: If I commit the project as a whole there are files with local paths which need to be edited from the person who checkouts. I could commit only the files that change.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529178/git-flash-builder-workflow-how-do-i-set-it-up-so-git-works-smoothly can help

Comment: Do you use some tool in eclipse to upload sources to git repository, or do you want to do it via cli ?

Comment: Incase you are using flex-builder , its a good idea to directly upload the flex project as a .zip or .fxp file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use flex, but here are some general rules for all source control:

Commit:

- **Human written code**
- Configuration files
- Referenced 3rd party libraries (that are not typically part of the standard environment)
- In some cases tools needed to build and run that are not standard (save people hunting and downloading if you can)

Ignore:

- **Generated code, that can be easily regenerated using a scripts, tools**

  - Generated CSS files if you write SASS/SCSS/LESS instead
  - Generated JS files if you write Coffeescript instead
- Build artifacts, build folders,
- Temporary files (e.g., some editors creating working files)

As an addendum for Git, I prefer to keep some non-code artifacts in submodules to avoid polluting the code repository. This can include:

- Large assets, images and videos in some cases
- Tools and executables (very handy if you reuse these tools for multiple projects)

This is not an exhaustive list and your environment probably dictates some deviation or adjustments here.  The first rules in